# ng2-pdf-viewer in angular not showing checkbox icon

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, jspdf, ng2-pdf-viewer

We are using ng2-pdf-viewer npm package for rendering pdf. we have checkboxes in pdf but while viewing pdf we are not able to view yes icon instead we are getting cross icon

when open in browser

[image]

when open using ng2-pdf-viewer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an underlying failing in the Mozilla PDF.js viewer component. Thus not a ng2-pdf-viewer issue. Has been raised before but unknown what Mozilla bugzilla status is.

[image]